# Split char array in C while keeping delimiters

Tags: c, regex, split

So I'm working in C and have a char array and I want to split it everytime there is a space, "(", ")", or "{". But, I want to keep those character delimiters. For example, if my input was

`void statement(int y){`

I want my output to be

`void
statement
(
int
y
)
{`

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: With a `for` loop that examines one character at a time.

Comment: So how about `printf("Hello world?");` :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the loop of your choice and a few conditional tests that basically boil down to:

1. if the current char is a delimiter;
2. if the previous char wasn't a delimiter, output a space before the delimiter;
3. if the delimiter (current char) is not a space, output char followed by newline.

(using the string of delimiters as the string in `strchr` and checking against the current char is a simple way of determining if the current char is a delim)

Putting that together in a short example, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    int c, last = 0;                    /* current & previous char */
    const char *delims = " (){}";       /* delimiters */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {    /* read each char */
        if (strchr (delims, c)) {       /* if delimiter */
            if (last && !strchr (delims, last)) /* if last not delimiter */
                putchar ('\n');         /* precede char with newline */
            if (c != ' ') {             /* if current not space */
                putchar (c);            /* output delimiter */
                putchar ('\n');         /* followed by newline */
            }
        }
        else    /* otherwise */
            putchar (c);                /* just output char */
        last = c;                       /* set last to current */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Given your input string, the output matches what you have provided.

```
$ printf "void statement(int y){" | ./bin/getchar_delims
void
statement
(
int
y
)
{
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `strpbrk`, which not only retains the delimiting chars by simply returning a pointer to the found delimiter, but also supports multiple delimiter characters.

For example, this should do what you want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *input = "void statement(int y){a";
    char *delims = " (){";
    char *remaining = input;
    char *token;

     // while we find delimiting characters
    while ((token = strpbrk(remaining, delims)) != NULL) {
         // print the characters between the last found delimiter (or string beginning) and current delimiter
        if (token - remaining > 0) {
            printf("%.*s\n", token - remaining, remaining);
        }

         // Also print the delimiting character itself
        printf("%c\n", *token);

         // Offset remaining search string to character after the found delimiter
        remaining = token + 1;
    }

     // Print any characters after the last delimiter
    printf("%s\n", remaining);

    return 0;
}
```

The output includes the spaces since you included  as a delimiter. If you don't want this, wrap the delimiter character printing in a condition like this:

```
    if (*token != ' ') {
        printf("%c\n", *token);
    }
```